# Semantic UI and overflow

Tags: semantic-ui

I am trying (with no success) use Semantic UI for application layout with list on the left that fills height of browser and scrolls its content AND form on the right that is fixed.

In pure HTML/CSS I would do it like this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/qFFvY/

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
<div class="row header">HEADER</div>
<div class="row body">
    <div class="left col vscroll">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in data">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right col vscroll">
        Form
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row footer">FOOTER</div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
     margin: 0
 }
 .row, .col {
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     border: dotted 1px red;
 }
 .left {
     width: 30%;
 }
 .right {
     left: 30%;
     right: 0px;
 }
 .row {
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
 }
 .col {
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
 }
 .vscroll {
     overflow-y: auto;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
 .body.row {
     top: 40px;
     bottom: 40px;
 }
 .footer.row {
     bottom: 0;
     height: 40px;
 }
```

I tried use Semantic UI Grid system and overflow+position:absolute list panel but it gets crazy 
Also putting Semantic UI components into layout from Fiddle makes lots of problems with inner components.

So, QUESTION: Is there a way to use Semantic UI CSS classes with extra styling to achieve responsive application layout with one list that fills height of browser and hides content with vertical scroolbar?

Comment: Do you want the sidebar list to disappear when you're close to the mobile threshold?

Comment: Actually this list has nothing to do with Semantic sidebar. Its just a list that has a form on the right - and i want the list to stay on mobile but form to dissapear.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. I think is not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a list that is scrollable. But I only have a static form on top. But as there is no other answer maybe this helps:
[image]

The code looks like:

```
<div>
 <div class="ui main fixed borderless menu">
      <div class="ui item">
 ... static form
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ui main text container">
      <div id="log-panel" class="ui relaxed divided list">
    <div class="item">
   ... list item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
   ...
    </div>
...
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only a little extra CSS was needed:

```
#log-panel {
    padding-top: 7em;
    max-height:calc(100vh - 4em);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 3rd July 2017 there is a "scrolling content" style available.
See closing note in https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4335

This might be able to help you with your full-page control, without the extra CSS.

Modal example:

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="scrolling content">
    <p>Very long content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```